# Cyclic subgroups of subgroups

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to find the subgroups of Y x X where Y is C3 and Z is C3. The question I'm trying to work out requires me to list all of the subgroups of this. I started off by drawing the lattice for it but from that point I'm pretty much stuck. I don't have a clue how to get the subgroups from that point on.

I don't know how to create a lattice drawing on here but I know the drawing is correct. I'm just stuck as to what the next point would be.

Comment: Do you know what normal subgroups are?

Comment: That's when the left coset and right coset are equal right?

Comment: @crystal_math Normal subgroups don't matter in an abelian context.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $G = C_3 \times C_3 = \langle a \rangle \times \langle b \rangle$. Then $G$ has $4$ subgroups of order $3$. These are:

- $H_1 = \langle (a,b) \rangle = \{(a,b), (a^2,b^2), (1,1)\}$,
- $H_2 = \langle (a,1) \rangle = \{(a,1), (a^2,1), (1,1)\}$,
- $H_3 = \langle (1,b) \rangle = \{(1,b), (1,b^2), (1,1)\}$,
- $H_4 = \langle (a^2,b)\rangle = \{(a^2,b), (a,b^2), (1,1)\}$.

Check that these $4$ subgroups exhaust all possibilities.

Comment: What about <1,1> and <a,b^2> ?

Comment: I gave you the proper non-trivial subgroups. Obviously $G$ also has the trivial subgroup and the whole group as subgroups. It's up to you to verify that those $4$ subgroups account for all subgroups of order $3$ in $G$.