# Finding the subgroups of cyclic groups

Tags: group-theory

Currently trying to work out all of the subgroups of $X \times Y$, $X = C_3 = \langle x \rangle$ and $Y = C_3 = \langle y \rangle$.

I know that $X = \{1, x, x^2\}$ and $Y = \{1, y, y^2\}$. I also know that
$$X \times Y =  \{(1,1), (1,y), (1,y^2), (x,1), (x,y), (x,y^2), (x^2, 1), (x^2, y), (x^2, y^2)\}.$$

I came up with these subgroups:
\begin{align*}
H_1 &= \{(1,1), (1,y), (1,y^2)\} \\
H_2 &= \{(1,1), (x,1), (x^2,1)\} \\
H_3 &= \{(1,1), (x,y), (x^2,y^2)\} \\
H_4 &= \{(1,1), (x,y^2), (x^2,y)\} \\
H_5 &= \{(1,1), (1,y), (1,y^2), (x,1), (x,y), (x,y^2), (x^2, 1), (x^2, y), (x^2, y^2)\}
\end{align*}

I would just like to double check with someone that these are correct and that they're ALL of the possible subgroups. If not, I'd appreciate someone helping me out and pointing out/explaining my mistakes.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What about the trivial subgroup?

Comment: Oh that's a good point, so there would be another subgroup of (1,1). Is that correct? Is that the only missing subgroup?

Comment: Why are you asking the same thing again when there is already an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3702828/cyclic-subgroups-of-subgroups/3702855?noredirect=1#comment7609938_3702855) to your question?

Comment: I wasn't aware there was an answer ...... I was just asking for clarification that my working out was correct.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thank you for informing me, I did that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to be a bit systematic here, to make sure that we have them all.

$X\times Y$ has $9$ elements. That means any subgroup has either $1$, $3$ or $9$ elements. The orders of $1$ and $9$ are easily handled (as long as you remember them in the first place). That leaves $3$.

Any subgroup with $3$ elements will be cyclic. So just take each non-identity element in the group, and see which cyclic group it generates, and you're done.

There are $8$ non-identity elements, and they all have order $3$, which should make it $8$ order $3$ subgroups... Except not really. Since each order $3$ subgroup has $2$ potential generators, there is some overlap: $\langle(x, y)\rangle = \langle (x^2, y^2)\rangle$, for instance. This means that the $8$ different cyclic-subgroup-generators make a total of $4$ subgroups. And you have found $4$, so you have them all. Good job!

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation and explanation!

Comment: This is a great explanation.